# Is there a front-end of Windows runas?

Tags: windows-10, runas

I want to be able to write scripts that execute privileged commands.

However I want users to be prompted via UI for executing these commands (then select "as Administrator" (like you can do with right-click) without needing to provide any password) and not via console password prompt.

Is there any such command for windows?

Comment: Have you ckecked Microsoft site? This [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb490994.aspx) for example.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32216421) from StackOverflow?
2. If these are PowerShell commands, have you tried appending `-Confirm` to the CMDlet? This will output a dialog box the technician has to click 'Yes' to continue.

That's what I do for scripts given to field technicians, so they can't say 'I didn't know what would happen'

Comment: 1 is what I am looking for.